# Ajax Auto refresh - Table not refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having a serious problem in my code and I can't manage to fix it.
I'm currently using Ajax to setTimeout and get the data from it.
The problem here is that it's not refreshing (if I go the page getdata.php via url it refreshes but I wanted to refresh without going to that page).

This is my current ajax script:

```
<div id="tableHolder"></div>

<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
    });

     function refreshTable(){
       $('#tableHolder').load('getdata.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
      });
     }

</script>
```

The code in getdata.php is the following one:

```
 <?php

require_once("config.php");
$req2 = mysqli_query($con, 'select user_id, user_name from users LIMIT 5');                                                                        
  while ($dnn = mysqli_fetch_array($req2)) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $dnn['user_id'] . "|</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $dnn['user_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    echo "</table>";        
  } 
?>
```

I can't find any solution to this problem so my last hope is on you StackOverflow!

Comment: may be you should use `setTimeout(refreshTable(), 1000);`

Comment: @Nagaraju same will also work as shown in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `$.load` method is serving you the cached data. You need to add some random text in url like timestamp

You can use like this

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
    refreshTable();
    });

     function refreshTable(){
       $('#tableHolder').load('getdata.php?time=' + new Date().getTime(), function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
      });
     }

</script>
```

Comment: `$.load` is getting data from server side (php) so I think there wont be any cache unless there is no change

Comment: @Nagaraju Actually OP is saying that he needs to loads the page to get the updated data. So maybe cache issue is what he is facing.

Comment: This answer seems to work for me, probably cache was always changing my data!

Comment: he wants to load div only not the page and fetching is from php, thats my point.

Comment: @Nagaraju Actually Browser seems to cache the response of same api if its hitting frequently. Check this http://www.ckode.dk/programming/avoiding-caching-with-jquery-load/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setTimeout` you can use `setInterval` with some querystring

```
function refreshTable(){
   setInterval(function(){  
    $('#tableHolder').load('getdata.php?v=1')
   }, 1000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Settimeout is usually used for one-time execution
Try setInterval instead if you want to repeat calling load function